# Problems with GCC "build file: no target in no project"

Tags: c, codeblocks

I have a problem with C. When I want to compile my sources codes, I see the message:

```
=== Build file: "no target" in "no project" (compiler: unknown) ===
```

The classic Hello world works, but I have this message.

[image]

I want to make a program that read all absolute directories and subdirectories recursively, print all names with 252 characters or more in a file. I use codeblocks and GNU gcc.

[image]

Comment: There are no errors.

Comment: Do you think that message is fine?

Comment: The next line is the important one.

Comment: This is certainly not a 'problem with GCC'. GCC did not emit this message. It is a problem with your IDE, if it is a problem at all.

Answer (score 3):

I have just had this problem with Codeblocks. Although I had a compiler.

The problem was that I have not saved the file with the correct extension - e.g. it was `Untitled4` instead of `Untitled4.c` or `Untitled4.cpp` (for c++). Simply renaming the file has worked.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem too but I managed to get it going. I had to go to New --> Project --> Console Application.

My guess is that an update has changed functionality or something. I distinctly remember that I could just simply add a new Empty File and then be able to debug and it run from there. Apparently not anymore. I now specifically have to go to the add new projects option and then choose the console application.

Don't forget to choose the C compiler and not C++ compiler when it walks you through the process.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same problem. So i found that i do have created a project file, but my files(.cpp, .h and other) files were not included in my project, to check that open your codeblock ide-> open your project-> and on the left hand side you will see a Management tab, which should contain all your file( if you are not able to see Management tab, just follow step: go to view panel  )

Answer (score 0):

While the process is active, you can´t run the  program.

Open the **Task Manager** and kill the process created by CodeBlocks (the same name of your project).

Answer (score 0):

Just create a new project and Copy and paste your texts into the new files. It will work.